# Environmental problems using testthat

Tags: r, testthat, nse

I have some delicate issues with environments that are currently manifesting themselves in my unit tests. My basic structure is this

- I have a main function `main` that has many arguments
- `wrapper` is a wrapper function (one of many) that pertains only to selected arguments of `main`
- `helper` is an intermediate helper function that is used by all wrapper functions

I use `eval` and `match.call()` to move between wrappers and the main function smoothly. **My issue now is that my tests work when I run them line by line, but not using `test_that()`.**

Here is a MWE that shows the problem. If you step through the lines in the test manually, the test passes. However, evaluating the whole `test_that()` chunk the test fails because one of the arguments can not be found.

```
library(testthat)

wrapper <- function(a, b) {
  fun_call <- as.list(match.call())
  ret <- helper(fun_call)
  return(ret)
}

helper <- function(fun_call) {
  fun_call[[1]] <- quote(main)
  fun_call <- as.call(fun_call)
  fun_eval <- eval(as.call(fun_call))
  return(fun_eval)
}

main <- function(a, b, c = 1) {
  ret <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)
  return(ret)
}

test_that("Test", {
  a <- 1
  b <- 2
  x <- wrapper(a = a, b = b)
  y <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 1)
  expect_equal(x, y)
})
```

With quite some confidence, I suspect I need to modify the default environment used by `eval` (i.e. `parent.frame()`), but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Defining helper within the body of wrapper might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to evaluate your call in your parent environment, not the local function environment. Change your helper to

```
helper <- function(fun_call) {
  fun_call[[1]] <- quote(main)
  fun_call <- as.call(fun_call)
  fun_eval <- eval.parent(fun_call, n=2)
  return(fun_eval)
}
```

This is assuming that `helper` is always called within `wrapper` which is called from somewhere else the parameters are defined.

It's not clear in this case that you really need all this non-standard evaulation. You might also consider a solution like

```
wrapper <- function(a, b) {
  helper(mget(ls()))
}
helper <- function(params) {
  do.call("main", params)
}
```

Here `wrapper` just bundles all it's parameters values into a list. Then you can just pass a list of parameters to `helper` and `do.call` will pass that list as parameters to your `main` function. This will evaluate the parameters of `wrapper` when you call it do you don't have to worry about the execution evironment.

Comment: This seems to work fine, but I'm puzzled as to why! The default in `eval.parent()` is `n=1`, and `eval.parent(expr, n)` is short for `eval(expr, parent.frame(n))`. So `eval.parent(expr, 1)` is `eval(expr, parent.frame(1))`, but the default environment in `eval` is `parent.frame()` --- and the default for `parent.frame()` is `n=1`! So, tl; dr: isn't `eval.parent(expr)` just the same as `eval(expr)`? (Evidently not, but I can't see why.)

Comment: Also, I just realized that this breaks down if in the test you set `a2 <- 1` and then `x <- wrapper(a = a2, b = b)`. So it seems as if this solution requires inputs to be named the same way as arguments?

Comment: @hejseb, First, it's important to note that when you pass parameters to functions they are evaluated in the calling environment but when you have a default parameter value, those are executed in the function environment which is different. So `parent.frame` behaves differently when passed to a function vs when it's a default parameter value. If helper is always called from within weapper, than you can do `fun_eval <- eval.parent(fun_call, n=2)` Or it would be even easier just to evaluate the parameters in `wrapper` before passing to `helper`. Is there a reason you are delaying evaluation?

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning a lot here. `wrapper` always calls `helper`, so that can safely be assumed. However, I wouldn't say that I intentionally am delaying evaluation --- that's just sort of what I've been experiencing. Originally, I wanted a bunch of wrappers that would all just modify certain arguments of `main`. Then I ended up with `match.call()` to avoid lots of hard-coded wrappers, and because all wrappers are structured the same way I put that stuff into the `helper`.

Comment: I can also add that in my case, `wrapper` also has default values and I need to keep track of those and which have been overridden. That I achieve using `formals()` and passing that too to the `helper`, so I do believe the intermediate function is necessary (although it came with some unexpected complications!).

Comment: It doesn't sound like form your use case that you should be using `match.call`. A more direct method might be something like: `wrapper <- function(a, b) {helper(mget(ls()))}; helper <- function(params) {do.call("main", params)}`

Comment: That does admittedly seem easier. I'll see if that fits my case. Thanks a lot!